# Javascript - How to access JSON array of objects

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm starting with JSON/Ajax development with Javascript and right now I have a scenario where I'm receiving a JSON string from the server and I want to build an object on the client side.
My server output is this:

```
[{"username":"user","mine":"[{"id":"1","artist":"Pearl Jam","name":"Rival"},{"id":"2","artist":"Pearl Jam","name":"Lukin"}]","default":"50"}]
```

On the JS side I'm doing this:

```
$.getJSON('?action=load',
        function(data)
        {

              window.User = data[0];
        });
```

I can print `window.User.username` and `window.User.default`. However I was expecting I could do something like `alert(window.User.mine[0].id)` as well, but it prints *[* (the first character of the songs array, so I'm assuming it is being interpreted as a string).
What I'm I doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"[{"id":"1","artist":"Pearl Jam","name":"Rival"},{"id":"2","artist":"Pearl Jam","name":"Lukin"}]"
```

should be this

```
[{"id":"1","artist":"Pearl Jam","name":"Rival"},{"id":"2","artist":"Pearl Jam","name":"Lukin"}]
```

The quotes around the arrays make them strings

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is malformed, so you get a string and not an array, thats the reason.

Your JSON should look like this:

```
[{"username":"user","mine":[{"id":"1","artist":"Pearl Jam","name":"Rival"},{"id":"2","artist":"Pearl Jam","name":"Lukin"}],"default":"50"}]
```

and then you will get the expected result

Comment: @fge: Even the syntax highlighter agrees on that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`window.User.mine.[0].id`

(after fixing your JSON as suggested...)

Comment: No, there shouldn't be a period before the array index.